# PCRE pattern that matches the in-delimiters text of a PCRE pattern

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm looking for a PCRE pattern that would match the text in between the delimiters of *any* valid PCRE pattern regardless of delimiters and modifiers used.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Match `text` in `/text/`, `{text}iu` etc.

Comment: Please also show us what you have tried that didn't work. Also, you know that you need to actually parse regex if you want to make sure that the pattern is valid?

Comment: @m.buettner I tried to look for the "standard" pattern to be used for this purpose, couldn't find.

Comment: @m.buettner Let the validity in this case be only determined by the validity of delimiters and modifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four paired delimiters, as far as I know: `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `<>`. All other allowed characters are just used twice. According to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), we can use any non-alphanumeric, non-whitespace, non-backslash character. So this pattern should work:

```
/
^
(?=([^a-zA-Z0-9\s\\\\])) # make sure the pattern begins with a valid delimiter
                         # and capture it into group 1
(?|                      # alternation for different delimiter types
                         # each alternative captures the pattern into group 2
  \((.*)\)               # handle (...)
|
  \[(.*)\]               # handle [...]
|
  \{(.*)\}               # handle {...}
|
  <(.*)>                 # handle <...>
|
  .(.*)\1                # handle all other delimiters with a backreference
)
[imsxeADSUXu]*           # allow for modifiers
$
/xs
```

If you use this `$pattern` in

```
preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);
```

then you'll find your desired result in `$matches[2]`.

Of course, this will accept a bunch of invalid patterns, because it does not ensure that the delimiter does not appear somewhere sooner in the pattern.